# Making arrow with a gradual colour

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I want to make an arrow that has gradual color as shown in the picture below:

[image]

First I wanted to make that arrow in one stroke, but I do not know how to make shaded color in `postaction`, so in the end I draw right side first, left side second and put shade over it in the middle.

Now two problems appear.

1. Color shading is not perfect, the middle colors do not correspond well to colors on the left and on the right.  I found out that the problem comes from the fact I opened `xcolor` in `cmyk` mode.
2. The thickness of the colored part of the arrow is not perfectly constant.  This cannot be seen on the picture but on the MWE-created PDF.

Is there any other way to create such effect, let's say in one stroke?  If not, how can colors created by `\draw` be aligned with colors created by `\shade`?

IMPORTANT EDIT: I would prefer a tweak to the existing solution, if possible.  Namely I am already using dozens of such arrows without color gradient going between two specified points following a bent path, i.e. (0,0) -- (0.5,0) arc (-90:0:0.5) -- (1,1).  Now I just need ONE straight but with gradient color.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-,postaction={draw,color=red!75,line width=3.85mm,shorten <=0.25mm}] (0,0) -- (-0.8,0);
\draw[line width=4.15mm,-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},postaction={draw,color=red!25,line width=3.85mm,shorten >=0.21mm}] (-0.8,0) -- (-1.6,0);
\shade[left color=red!25,right color=red!75] (-0.6,-0.5*3.85mm) rectangle (-1.0,0.5*3.85mm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What version of `tikz` are you using? CMYK shadings are only supported since version 3.1.3. Before that you need to load the `pgf-cmykshadings` package between `xcolor` and `tikz`. If you are using an older version, you will see the colour mismatch because the solid colours are CMYK and shading is RGB.

Comment: @DavidPurton Aaaaaaagh, I should update MikTeX more often! After update colors match perfectly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Explanation

Relating to the question of this comment:

> I am impressed by the amount of effort put into the solution. As you understand both solutions, what would you recommend me to use, `overlapping` or `postaction` solution? – [Pygmalion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3450/pygmalion)

With the first approach you can also use `postaction`, but `shading path` trims the arrow, concretely,  in the case of the path `(0,0) -- (0.5,0) arc (-90:0:0.5) -- (1,1)` (not in the others):

[image]

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},postaction={shading=shading1,shading angle=45,shading path={draw=transparent!0,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},line width=3.85mm,shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}}] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) arc (0:90:0.5) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},postaction={shading=shading1,shading path={draw=transparent!0,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},line width=3.85mm,shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}}] (0,0) -- (1.6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},postaction={shading=shading1,shading angle=37,shading path={draw=transparent!0,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},line width=3.85mm,shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}}] (0,0) -- ++(15:1) -- +(45:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},postaction={shading=shading1,shading angle=10,shading path={draw=transparent!0,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},line width=3.85mm,shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}}] (0,0) arc (180:50:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Therefore, with an "overlapping" works well, because both arrows are trimmed.

With the second/third approach (third code version) you can pass other options such as `shading xsep=<length>` and `shade path` sorts everything else out, see please the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137438/89320) of [Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow):

[image]

Of course you can also overlap with the second/third approach.

> #### IMHO: For straight arrows the best solution is [user191948](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/191948/user191948)´s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498096/89320). For bend arrows you have two approaches, marmot´s and mine.

## Third approach, with improved `postaction`:

The next improvements are based on the comment of [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot), see below:

> If you load the `bending` library and add `bend` to all the arrows along curved paths, the result looks much nicer IMHO. Also adjusting the `shading angle` may improve the appearance. – [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot)

Output `shading1`:

[image]

Output `shading2`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta,shapes,bending,shadings}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137357/how-to-draw-an-arrow-with-two-colors
\makeatletter
\newif\iftikz@shading@path

\tikzset{
    % There are three circumstances in which the fading sep is needed:
    % 1. Arrows which do not update the bounding box (which is most of them).
    % 2. Line caps/joins and mitres that extend outside the natural bounding 
    %    box of the path (these are not calculated by PGF).
    % 3. Other reasons that haven't been anticipated.
    shading xsep/.store in=\tikz@pathshadingxsep,
    shading ysep/.store in=\tikz@pathshadingysep,
    shading sep/.style={shading xsep=#1, shading ysep=#1},
    shading sep=0.0cm,
}

\def\tikz@shadepath#1{% 
    % \tikz@addmode installs the `modes' (e.g., fill, draw, shade) 
    % to be applied to the path. It isn't usualy for doing more
    % changes to the path's construction.
    \iftikz@shading@path%
    \else%
    \tikz@shading@pathtrue%
    % Get the current path.
    \pgfgetpath\tikz@currentshadingpath%
    % Get the shading sep without setting any other keys.
    \begingroup%
    \pgfsys@beginscope% <- may not be necessary
    \tikzset{#1}%
    \xdef\tikz@tmp{\noexpand\def\noexpand\tikz@pathshadingxsep{\tikz@pathshadingxsep}%
        \noexpand\def\noexpand\tikz@pathshadingysep{\tikz@pathshadingysep}}%
    \pgfsys@endscope%
    \endgroup
    \tikz@tmp%
    % Get the boudning box of the current path size including the shading sep
    \pgfextract@process\pgf@shadingpath@southwest{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@pathminx}{\pgf@pathminy}}%
        {\pgfpoint{-\tikz@pathshadingxsep}{-\tikz@pathshadingysep}}}%%
    \pgfextract@process\pgf@shadingpath@northeast{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@pathmaxx}{\pgf@pathmaxy}}%
        {\pgfpoint{\tikz@pathshadingxsep}{\tikz@pathshadingysep}}}%
    % Clear the path
    \pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty%                          
    % Save the current drawing mode and options.
    \let\tikz@options@saved=\tikz@options%
    \let\tikz@mode@saved=\tikz@mode%
    \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
    \let\tikz@mode=\pgfutil@empty%
    % \tikz@options are processed later on.
    \tikz@addoption{%
        \pgfinterruptpath%
        \pgfinterruptpicture%
        \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=.]
            \pgfscope%
            \tikzset{shade path/.style=}% Make absolutely sure shade path is not inherited.
            \path \pgfextra{%
                % Set the softpath. Any transformations,draw=none} in #1 will have no effect.
                % This will *not* update the bounding box...
                \pgfsetpath\tikz@currentshadingpath%
                % ...so it is done manually.
                \pgf@shadingpath@southwest
                \expandafter\pgf@protocolsizes{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}%
                \pgf@shadingpath@northeast%
                \expandafter\pgf@protocolsizes{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}%
                % Install the drawing modes and options.
                \let\tikz@options=\tikz@options@saved%
                \let\tikz@mode=\tikz@mode@saved%
            };
            % Now get the bounding box of the picture.
            \xdef\pgf@shadingboundingbox@southwest{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@picminx}{\the\pgf@picminy}}%
            \xdef\pgf@shadingboundingbox@northeast{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@picmaxx}{\the\pgf@picmaxy}}%
            \endpgfscope
        \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
        \endpgfinterruptpicture%
        \endpgfinterruptpath%
        % Install a rectangle that covers the shaded/faded path picture.
        \pgftransformreset%
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgf@shadingboundingbox@southwest}{\pgf@shadingboundingbox@northeast}%
        %
        % Reset all modes.
        \let\tikz@path@picture=\pgfutil@empty%
        \tikz@mode@fillfalse%
        \tikz@mode@drawfalse%
        %\tikz@mode@tipsfalse%   <- To have successful compilation with pgf-tikz v3.0.1a
        \tikz@mode@doublefalse%
        \tikz@mode@clipfalse%
        \tikz@mode@boundaryfalse%
        \tikz@mode@fade@pathfalse%
        \tikz@mode@fade@scopefalse%
        % Now install shading options.
        \tikzset{#1}%
        \tikz@mode%
        % Make the fading happen.
        \def\tikz@path@fading{.}%
        \tikz@mode@fade@pathtrue%
        \tikz@fade@adjustfalse%
        % Shift the fading to the mid point of the rectangle
        \pgfpointscale{0.5}{\pgfpointadd{\pgf@shadingboundingbox@southwest}{\pgf@shadingboundingbox@northeast}}%
        \edef\tikz@fade@transform{shift={(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)}}%
        \pgfsetfading{\tikz@path@fading}{\tikz@do@fade@transform}%
        \tikz@mode@fade@pathfalse%              
    }%
    \fi%
}
\tikzset{
    shade path/.code={%
        \tikz@addmode{\tikz@shadepath{#1}}%
    }
}
\makeatother % <- To close the \makeatletter call
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197793/how-to-draw-gradient-arrows-with-tikz
\makeatletter
\def\createshadingfromlist#1#2#3{%
    \pgfutil@tempcnta=0\relax
    \pgfutil@for\pgf@tmp:={#3}\do{\advance\pgfutil@tempcnta by1}%
    \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta=1\relax%
    \edef\pgf@spec{color(0)=(#3);color(100)=(#3)}%
    \else%
    \pgfmathparse{50/(\pgfutil@tempcnta-1)}\let\pgf@step=\pgfmathresult%
    %
    \pgfutil@tempcntb=1\relax%
    \pgfutil@for\pgf@tmp:={#3}\do{%
        \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb=1\relax%
        \edef\pgf@spec{color(0)=(\pgf@tmp);color(25)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
        \else%
        \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb<\pgfutil@tempcnta\relax%
        \pgfmathparse{25+\pgf@step/4+(\pgfutil@tempcntb-1)*\pgf@step}%
        \edef\pgf@spec{\pgf@spec;color(\pgfmathresult)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
        \else%
        \edef\pgf@spec{\pgf@spec;color(75)=(\pgf@tmp);color(100)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
        \fi%
        \fi%
        \advance\pgfutil@tempcntb by1\relax%
    }%
    \fi%
    \csname pgfdeclare#2shading\endcsname{#1}{100}\pgf@spec%
}
\makeatother

\createshadingfromlist{shading1}{horizontal}{red,white}
\createshadingfromlist{shading2}{horizontal}{red,yellow,green,cyan,blue}

\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},postaction={draw=white, shade path={shading xsep=0.6cm,shading=shading1,shading angle=45}, line width=3.85mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) arc (0:90:0.5) -- (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},postaction={draw=white, shade path={shading xsep=-0.5cm, shading=shading1},line width=3.85mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}] (0,0) -- (1.6,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},postaction={draw=white, shade path={shading xsep=0cm, shading=shading1,shading angle=37},line width=3.85mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}] (0,0) -- ++(15:1) -- +(45:1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},postaction={draw=white, shade path={shading xsep=0cm, shading=shading1,shading angle=10},line width=3.85mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120,bend]},shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}] (0,0) arc (180:50:2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Second approach, with `postaction`:

With the third version of the answer [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137438/89320) is also possible to achieve the same result with `postaction`:

Output `shading1`:

[image]

Output `shading2`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta,shapes}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137357/how-to-draw-an-arrow-with-two-colors
\makeatletter
\newif\iftikz@shading@path

\tikzset{
    % There are three circumstances in which the fading sep is needed:
    % 1. Arrows which do not update the bounding box (which is most of them).
    % 2. Line caps/joins and mitres that extend outside the natural bounding 
    %    box of the path (these are not calculated by PGF).
    % 3. Other reasons that haven't been anticipated.
    shading xsep/.store in=\tikz@pathshadingxsep,
    shading ysep/.store in=\tikz@pathshadingysep,
    shading sep/.style={shading xsep=#1, shading ysep=#1},
    shading sep=0.0cm,
}

\def\tikz@shadepath#1{% 
    % \tikz@addmode installs the `modes' (e.g., fill, draw, shade) 
    % to be applied to the path. It isn't usualy for doing more
    % changes to the path's construction.
    \iftikz@shading@path%
    \else%
        \tikz@shading@pathtrue%
        % Get the current path.
        \pgfgetpath\tikz@currentshadingpath%
        % Get the shading sep without setting any other keys.
        \begingroup%
            \pgfsys@beginscope% <- may not be necessary
            \tikzset{#1}%
            \xdef\tikz@tmp{\noexpand\def\noexpand\tikz@pathshadingxsep{\tikz@pathshadingxsep}%
                \noexpand\def\noexpand\tikz@pathshadingysep{\tikz@pathshadingysep}}%
            \pgfsys@endscope%
        \endgroup
        \tikz@tmp%
        % Get the boudning box of the current path size including the shading sep
        \pgfextract@process\pgf@shadingpath@southwest{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@pathminx}{\pgf@pathminy}}%
            {\pgfpoint{-\tikz@pathshadingxsep}{-\tikz@pathshadingysep}}}%%
        \pgfextract@process\pgf@shadingpath@northeast{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@pathmaxx}{\pgf@pathmaxy}}%
            {\pgfpoint{\tikz@pathshadingxsep}{\tikz@pathshadingysep}}}%
        % Clear the path
        \pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty%                          
        % Save the current drawing mode and options.
        \let\tikz@options@saved=\tikz@options%
        \let\tikz@mode@saved=\tikz@mode%
        \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
        \let\tikz@mode=\pgfutil@empty%
        % \tikz@options are processed later on.
        \tikz@addoption{%
            \pgfinterruptpath%
            \pgfinterruptpicture%
                \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=.]
                \pgfscope%
                    \tikzset{shade path/.style=}% Make absolutely sure shade path is not inherited.
                    \path \pgfextra{%
                        % Set the softpath. Any transformations,draw=none} in #1 will have no effect.
                        % This will *not* update the bounding box...
                        \pgfsetpath\tikz@currentshadingpath%
                        % ...so it is done manually.
                        \pgf@shadingpath@southwest
                        \expandafter\pgf@protocolsizes{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}%
                        \pgf@shadingpath@northeast%
                        \expandafter\pgf@protocolsizes{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}%
                        % Install the drawing modes and options.
                        \let\tikz@options=\tikz@options@saved%
                        \let\tikz@mode=\tikz@mode@saved%
                    };
                    % Now get the bounding box of the picture.
                    \xdef\pgf@shadingboundingbox@southwest{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@picminx}{\the\pgf@picminy}}%
                    \xdef\pgf@shadingboundingbox@northeast{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@picmaxx}{\the\pgf@picmaxy}}%
                    \endpgfscope
                \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
            \endpgfinterruptpicture%
            \endpgfinterruptpath%
            % Install a rectangle that covers the shaded/faded path picture.
            \pgftransformreset%
            \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgf@shadingboundingbox@southwest}{\pgf@shadingboundingbox@northeast}%
            %
            % Reset all modes.
            \let\tikz@path@picture=\pgfutil@empty%
            \tikz@mode@fillfalse%
            \tikz@mode@drawfalse%
            %\tikz@mode@tipsfalse%   <- To have successful compilation with pgf-tikz v3.0.1a
            \tikz@mode@doublefalse%
            \tikz@mode@clipfalse%
            \tikz@mode@boundaryfalse%
            \tikz@mode@fade@pathfalse%
            \tikz@mode@fade@scopefalse%
            % Now install shading options.
            \tikzset{#1}%
            \tikz@mode%
            % Make the fading happen.
            \def\tikz@path@fading{.}%
            \tikz@mode@fade@pathtrue%
            \tikz@fade@adjustfalse%
            % Shift the fading to the mid point of the rectangle
            \pgfpointscale{0.5}{\pgfpointadd{\pgf@shadingboundingbox@southwest}{\pgf@shadingboundingbox@northeast}}%
            \edef\tikz@fade@transform{shift={(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)}}%
            \pgfsetfading{\tikz@path@fading}{\tikz@do@fade@transform}%
            \tikz@mode@fade@pathfalse%              
        }%
    \fi%
}
\tikzset{
    shade path/.code={%
        \tikz@addmode{\tikz@shadepath{#1}}%
    }
}
\makeatother % <- To close the \makeatletter call
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197793/how-to-draw-gradient-arrows-with-tikz
\makeatletter
\def\createshadingfromlist#1#2#3{%
    \pgfutil@tempcnta=0\relax
    \pgfutil@for\pgf@tmp:={#3}\do{\advance\pgfutil@tempcnta by1}%
    \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta=1\relax%
    \edef\pgf@spec{color(0)=(#3);color(100)=(#3)}%
    \else%
    \pgfmathparse{50/(\pgfutil@tempcnta-1)}\let\pgf@step=\pgfmathresult%
    %
    \pgfutil@tempcntb=1\relax%
    \pgfutil@for\pgf@tmp:={#3}\do{%
        \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb=1\relax%
        \edef\pgf@spec{color(0)=(\pgf@tmp);color(25)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
        \else%
        \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb<\pgfutil@tempcnta\relax%
        \pgfmathparse{25+\pgf@step/4+(\pgfutil@tempcntb-1)*\pgf@step}%
        \edef\pgf@spec{\pgf@spec;color(\pgfmathresult)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
        \else%
        \edef\pgf@spec{\pgf@spec;color(75)=(\pgf@tmp);color(100)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
        \fi%
        \fi%
        \advance\pgfutil@tempcntb by1\relax%
    }%
    \fi%
    \csname pgfdeclare#2shading\endcsname{#1}{100}\pgf@spec%
}
\makeatother

\createshadingfromlist{shading1}{vertical}{red,white}
\createshadingfromlist{shading1b}{horizontal}{red,white}
\createshadingfromlist{shading2}{vertical}{red,yellow,green,cyan,blue}
\createshadingfromlist{shading2b}{horizontal}{red,yellow,green,cyan,blue}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},postaction={draw=white, shade path={shading xsep=0.6cm, shading=shading1}, line width=3.85mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) arc (0:90:0.5) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},postaction={draw=white, shade path={shading xsep=0cm, shading=shading1b},line width=3.85mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}] (0,0) -- (1.6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},postaction={draw=white, shade path={shading xsep=0cm, shading=shading1b},line width=3.85mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}] (0,0) -- ++(15:1) -- +(45:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw,line width=4.15mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},postaction={draw=white, shade path={shading xsep=0cm, shading=shading1b},line width=3.85mm,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}] (0,0) arc (180:50:2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## First approach, with "overlapping":

Based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497994/89320) to [tikz: draw multicolor curve with smooth gradient](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497977/tikz-draw-multicolor-curve-with-smooth-gradient/497994#497994), which relies on other two ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137438/89320),[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197867/89320)) given by [Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow), you can also achieve a color gradient with the `shaping path` and the commands of the Shading library (Chapter 69, p.737): `left color=<color>` and `right color=<color>` (or `top color=<color>` and `bottom color=<color>`).

For a multicolor gradient, you can define:

```
\createshadingfromlist{<name>}{<direction>}{<colors>}
```

Output `shading1`:

[image]

Output `shading2`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,fadings,arrows.meta}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137357/how-to-draw-an-arrow-with-two-colors
\makeatletter
\newif\iftikz@shading@path

\tikzset{
    % There are three circumstances in which the fading sep is needed:
    % 1. Arrows which do not update the bounding box (which is most of them).
    % 2. Line caps/joins and mitres that extend outside the natural bounding 
    %    box of the path (these are not calculated by PGF).
    % 3. Other reasons that haven't been anticipated.
    fading xsep/.store in=\pgfpathfadingxsep,
    fading ysep/.store in=\pgfpathfadingysep,
    fading sep/.style={fading xsep=#1, fading ysep=#1},
    fading sep=0.0cm,
    shading path/.code={%
        % Prevent this stuff happning recursively.
        \iftikz@shading@path%
        \else%
        \tikz@shading@pathtrue%
        % \tikz@addmode installs the `modes' (e.g., fill, draw, shade) 
        % to be applied to the path. It isn't usualy for doing more
        % changes to the path's construction.
        \tikz@addmode{%
            \pgfgetpath\pgf@currentfadingpath%
            % Get the boudning box of the current path size including the fading sep
            \pgfextract@process\pgf@fadingpath@southwest{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@pathminx}{\pgf@pathminy}}%
                {\pgfpoint{-\pgfpathfadingxsep}{-\pgfpathfadingysep}}}%%
            \pgfextract@process\pgf@fadingpath@northeast{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@pathmaxx}{\pgf@pathmaxy}}%
                {\pgfpoint{\pgfpathfadingxsep}{\pgfpathfadingysep}}}%
            % Clear the path
            \pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty%                          
            % Interrupt the path and picture to create a fading.
            \pgfinterruptpath%
            \pgfinterruptpicture%
            \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=.]
                \path [shade=none,fill=none, #1] \pgfextra{%
                    % Set the softpath. Any transformations in #1 will have no effect.
                    % This will *not* update the bounding box...
                    \pgfsetpath\pgf@currentfadingpath%
                    % ...so it is done manually.
                    \pgf@fadingpath@southwest
                    \expandafter\pgf@protocolsizes{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}%
                    \pgf@fadingpath@northeast%
                    \expandafter\pgf@protocolsizes{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}%
                };
                % Now get the bounding of the picture.
                \xdef\pgf@fadingboundingbox@southwest{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@picminx}{\the\pgf@picminy}}%
                \xdef\pgf@fadingboundingbox@northeast{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@picmaxx}{\the\pgf@picmaxy}}%
                %
            \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
            \endpgfinterruptpicture%
            \endpgfinterruptpath%
            % Install a rectangle that covers the shaded/faded path picture.                                
            \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgf@fadingboundingbox@southwest}{\pgf@fadingboundingbox@northeast}%
            % Make the fading happen.
            \def\tikz@path@fading{.}%
            \tikz@mode@fade@pathtrue%
            \tikz@fade@adjustfalse%10pt
            % Shift the fading to the mid point of the rectangle
            \pgfpointscale{0.5}{\pgfpointadd{\pgf@fadingboundingbox@southwest}{\pgf@fadingboundingbox@northeast}}%
            \edef\tikz@fade@transform{shift={(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)}}%
        }%
        \fi%
    }
}
\makeatother
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197793/how-to-draw-gradient-arrows-with-tikz
\makeatletter
\def\createshadingfromlist#1#2#3{%
    \pgfutil@tempcnta=0\relax
    \pgfutil@for\pgf@tmp:={#3}\do{\advance\pgfutil@tempcnta by1}%
    \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta=1\relax%
    \edef\pgf@spec{color(0)=(#3);color(100)=(#3)}%
    \else%
    \pgfmathparse{50/(\pgfutil@tempcnta-1)}\let\pgf@step=\pgfmathresult%
    %
    \pgfutil@tempcntb=1\relax%
    \pgfutil@for\pgf@tmp:={#3}\do{%
        \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb=1\relax%
        \edef\pgf@spec{color(0)=(\pgf@tmp);color(25)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
        \else%
        \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb<\pgfutil@tempcnta\relax%
        \pgfmathparse{25+\pgf@step/4+(\pgfutil@tempcntb-1)*\pgf@step}%
        \edef\pgf@spec{\pgf@spec;color(\pgfmathresult)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
        \else%
        \edef\pgf@spec{\pgf@spec;color(75)=(\pgf@tmp);color(100)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
        \fi%
        \fi%
        \advance\pgfutil@tempcntb by1\relax%
    }%
    \fi%
    \csname pgfdeclare#2shading\endcsname{#1}{100}\pgf@spec%
}
\makeatother

\createshadingfromlist{shading0}{vertical}{black}
\createshadingfromlist{shading1}{vertical}{red,white}
\createshadingfromlist{shading2}{vertical}{red,yellow,green,cyan,blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[shading=shading0,shading path={draw=transparent!0,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},line width=4.15mm,}]  (0,0) -- (0.5,0) arc (0:90:0.5) -- (1,1);
\path[shading=shading1,shading path={draw=transparent!0,{Triangle Cap[reversed,cap angle=120]}-{Triangle Cap[cap angle=120]},line width=3.85mm,shorten <=0.25mm,shorten >=0.21mm}] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) arc (0:90:0.5) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### TODO:

- Must: the line color has to be black.
- Optional: the color gradient has to follow the direction of the arrow

Comment: For my use it is not important that color gradient follows direction, as I need this only for straight arrows.  But black outline line is a must.  (Also there was an error in path, I apologise.)

Comment: If you load the `bending` library and add `bend` to all the arrows along curved paths, the result looks much nicer IMHO. Also adjusting the `shading angle` may improve the appearance.

Comment: I am impressed by the amount of effort put into the solution.  As you understand both solutions, what would you recommend me to use, `overlapping` or `postaction` solution?

Answer (score 6):

The `shapes` library has a special shape called "signal". Using this one can shade the whole shape in one go:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[signal, draw,minimum width=1cm, signal from=east, signal to=west,shade, right color=red!75, left color=red!25] at (0,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but usually I have to draw this kind of arrows between two points, and sometimes they have to bend.

Comment: @Pygmalion do you know https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/tikz-shading-a-path-without-any-filling ?

Comment: This solution does not have the black edge around the arrow

Comment: @Pygmalion I cannot reproduce the problem with your shading, but maybe try `\PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk}{xcolor}
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}` with the code from your question?

Comment: `pgf-cmykshadings` is no longer needed. It has been now been incorporated into the core `pgf` package. So the OP example will produce a CMYK shading. (I need to update `pgf-cmykshadings` so that it does nothing with newer versions of `pgf` but haven't done that yet.)

Comment: Although... reading the OP question more carefully, perhaps an older version of `tikz` is in use, in which case `pgf-cmykshadings` will help. Sorry!

Comment: @DavidPurton  Aaaaaaagh, I should update MikTeX more often!  After update colors match perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

This combines the shape from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498096/121799) with some of the aspects of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432147/121799), where a similar problem was addressed. (However, this uses `show path construction` instead of a `to path` because this is arguably slightly easier to deal with.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.symbols,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
 signal arrow/.style={decorate,decoration={show path construction,  
 lineto code={
        \path let \p1 = ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)-(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$),
            \n1 = {int(mod(scalar(atan2(\y1,\x1))+360, 360))},
            \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        in
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
        node[signal,midway,sloped,left color=red,right color=red!20,draw,
        signal from=west, signal to=east,minimum width=\n2-\pgflinewidth,
             inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=5pt,shading angle=\n1+90,
             anchor=center,#1]{};
  }}},
  signal arrow/.default= % empty default
]
    \path[signal arrow] (0,0) to (1,2);
    \path (3,0) node[circle,inner sep=2pt,fill] (A) {}
    (5,3) node[circle,inner sep=2pt,fill] (B) {};
    \path[signal arrow] (A) to (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just as proof of principle: a minor modification of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496870/121799). At this point I do not have enough motivation to polish this. This will make more sense IMHO when it is clear where the journey will go.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\newcounter{parrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[record path/.style={/utils/exec=\tikzset{parrow/.cd,#1},
  decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0 with
    {\setcounter{parrow}{1}%\typeout{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
    \path (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/dist}/2) coordinate (parrowt-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/name}-\number\value{parrow})
   (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/dist}/2)coordinate (parrowb-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/name}-\number\value{parrow});
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mystep}{(\pgfdecoratedpathlength-4pt)/int(1+(\pgfdecoratedpathlength-4pt)/2pt)}
     \xdef\mystep{\mystep}},
  mark=between positions 2pt and 1 step \mystep pt with {\stepcounter{parrow}%
   \path (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/dist}/2) coordinate (parrowt-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/name}-\number\value{parrow})
   (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/dist}/2)coordinate (parrowb-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/name}-\number\value{parrow})
   (0,0) coordinate (parrowm-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/parrow/name}-\number\value{parrow});}
    }},reconstruct top/.style={insert path={plot[variable=\t,samples at={1,...,\number\value{parrow}},smooth] (parrowt-#1-\t)}},
  reconstruct bottom/.style={insert path={plot[variable=\t,samples at={\number\value{parrow},\the\numexpr\value{parrow}-1,...,1},smooth]
  (parrowb-#1-\t)}},
  font=\sffamily,nodes={circle,draw},parrow area/.style={insert path={
  (parrowt-#1-1) [reconstruct top=#1] -- (parrowb-#1-\number\value{parrow}) 
    [reconstruct bottom=#1]  -- (parrowt-#1-1)}},
  parrow/.cd,dist/.initial=3.14pt,step/.initial=2pt,name/.initial={}]
 \path (0,0) node (A) {A} (3,1) node (B) {B} ;
 \path[record path={name=AB,dist=5pt}] (A) to[bend left] (B);
 \addtocounter{parrow}{-2}
 \draw let \p1=($(B)-(A)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in [left color=red,right
 color=red!20,shading angle=\n1+90]
 [reconstruct top=AB] -- (parrowm-AB-\the\numexpr\value{parrow}+2)
 -- (parrowb-AB-\number\value{parrow})
  [reconstruct bottom=AB]
  -- (parrowm-AB-3) -- (parrowt-AB-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also make a banded arrow with this solution ((0,0) -- (0.5,0) arc (0:90:0.5) -- (1,1) )?   (in that case not necessarily with gradient color)

Comment: @Pygmalion Bended arrows can be done along the lines of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432143/121799) and/or [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471222/121799), which already has arrows which change the color. So the answer is yes, but IMHO this is a separate question.

Comment: OK the first post does show outlined arrows but different tips and no inside color gradient.  So you think the solution from the first post could be adapted relating to this two issues?  If yes, I will open a new question if no satisfactory solutions are provided to this question.  (I was hoping for the adaptation of the MWE because I already have dozens of such bent arrows in my document and now I only need one straight but with color gradient.

Comment: @Pygmalion I believe everything can be done as long as it is very clear what the desired outcome is. If you do not want a color gradient, then I could probably add some rather simple code for the arrow of this type along the arc. With color gradient it is somewhat more involved.

Comment: The idea is having an outlined arrow (a) that have constant color following path (0,0) -- (0.5,0) arc (0:90:0.5) -- (1,1)  and (b) that has gradient color following straight line (0,0) -- (2,0).  It should be possible to change the total thickness of the arrow (constant along the arrow).  Is something like that actually possible?

Comment: @Pygmalion Yes, sure, it is possible. The question is whether anyone will be interested in spelling this out if you put these requests in a comment. Normally others will expect you to try things, and if you get stuck you will have an MWE that you can post and others can use as a basis for their answer.

Comment: Yes, but in fact this is I am doing.  I have a working situation that (maybe) needs only a small tweak to get filled with the gradient color in straight situation.

Comment: @Pygmalion Maybe you are missing [this ingredient](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137438/121799)? I can only guess. It would be much easier if you asked a new question with all the details, which has the further advantage that many will look at this, and you get more feedback.

Comment: Do not know.  I am not that experienced to really understand what is going on.  Anyway, thanks for the discussion and maybe someone comes up with something useful to me.