# How do I use spath3 package to shading a path?

Tags: tikz-path

[Georges Dupéron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327713/117214)'s  solution of the question  ["Tikz: Shading a path without any filling"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/tikz-shading-a-path-without-any-filling/134297) is definitely what I need and it's an excellent solution. Since the  [`spath package`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files) has had an improve version ([`spath3 package`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3))  and been released on CTAN, I want to change [Georges Dupéron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327713/117214)'s  solution to use [`spath3`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3) instead. However, I'm a beginner in LaTeX from China and can't understand the source code of `spath3`, especially the ExplSyntax in the code. So I just changed the line

```
\usepackage{spath}% for "use path", from the TeX.SX
```

in the file  `fade-no-fill.sty` to

```
\usepackage{spath3}% for "use path", from the TeX.SX
```

then run the `main.tex` with `pdflatex main.tex`, and I got this error message:

```
! Package pgf Error: Unknown class 'spath'.
```

I only figured out that this line

```
\pgfoonew \thepathsav=new spath(\tmppath)
```

in the file  `fade-no-fill.sty` cause this error.

Now I don't know what to do!

Can someone help me to do this?

Some explanation on how to use the `spath3` package would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Where did you get the `spaht3.sty` from? Appearantly you have to get the `spath3.dtx`, run `pdflatex spath3.dtx` to get the `spath3.sty`. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes,I download the `spath3.dtx` then run `pdflatex spath3.dtx`  to get the `spath3.sty`.Got the error mentioned in the question. When I use `\usepackage{spath}` It works very well.I wonder how to use `\usepackage{spath3}` to do the same thing as use `\usepackage{spath}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Update 2021-07-13:* A more recent version of this code is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567029/86

---

Firstly, [`spath3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) *is* on CTAN and is part of TeXLive so doesn't need to be separately downloaded.

Secondly, it does feel slightly overkill to be using it in this context, but I don't know enough about how fadings work to be able to extract only the needed parts.  What is needed is the facility to save and restore a path (which is easy enough to do without `spath3`) but *also* to restore the bounding box of that path (which ought to be doable without `spath3`, but my initial experiments dismally failed).

So here's the original code modified to use `spath3`.  It works on the code from the original answer, but I haven't tested it on anything else.  I've also removed some unnecessary code from the original.

The original document is unchanged:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134283/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fade-no-fill}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[style=help lines] (0,-2) grid[step=1cm] (2,0);
  \path[
    fade path but don't fill={
      very thick,
      transparent!20,
      ->
    }{
      top color=blue!80,
      bottom color=green!80,
    },
  ] (0cm,0cm) .. controls +(0cm,-1cm) and +(0cm,1cm) .. (1cm,-2cm);


  \begin{scope}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
    % Circles, each with a distinct fading
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{18*\i}
      \path[
        fade path but don't fill={
          very thick,
          transparent!\j,
        }{
          top color=green!80,
          bottom color=blue!80,
          shading angle=45,
        },
      ] (1+\i,-\i) circle (\i mm);
    }

    % Circles, with a global fading
    \path[
      fade path but don't fill={
        very thick,
        transparent!60,
      }{
        top color=blue!80,
        bottom color=green!80,
      },
    ] foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
      (\i-1,-\i-3) circle (\i mm)
    };
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and `fade-no-fill.sty` is now:

```
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327713/86}
\usetikzlibrary{math}%
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}%
\usepackage{spath3}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% needed so that bounding boxes correctly include arrows.

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_if_exist:NF \spath_set_current_softpath:n {

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \spath_set_current_softpath:n #1
{
  \spath_get:nnN {#1} {min bb} \l__spath_tmpa_tl
  \exp_last_unbraced:NV \pgf@protocolsizes\l__spath_tmpa_tl

  \spath_get:nnN {#1} {max bb} \l__spath_tmpa_tl
  \exp_last_unbraced:NV \pgf@protocolsizes\l__spath_tmpa_tl

  \spath_get:nnN {#1} {path} \l__spath_tmpa_tl
  \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\l__spath_tmpa_tl
}
}
\tikzset{restore~ soft~ path/.code={%
    \spath_set_current_softpath:n {#1}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{
  fade path but don't fill/.style 2 args={
    preaction={save spath=fadingpath,},
    postaction={
      /utils/exec={
        \coordinate (oldbb-ne) at (current bounding box.north east);
        \coordinate (oldbb-sw) at (current bounding box.south west);
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tempfade]%
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \draw[restore soft path=fadingpath,#1];
        \coordinate (temp-fade-bb-ne) at (current bounding box.north east);
        \coordinate (temp-fade-bb-sw) at (current bounding box.south west);
        \coordinate (temp-fade-bb-center) at (current bounding box.center);
        \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
        %
        \useasboundingbox (oldbb-ne) rectangle (oldbb-sw);
        %
        \tikzmath{
          coordinate \ctempfadebbcenter;
          \ctempfadebbcenter = (temp-fade-bb-center);
        }
        \tikzset{tempstyle/.style/.expand once={#2}}
        \path[
          path fading=tempfade,
          fit fading=false,
          fading transform={
            yshift=\ctempfadebbcentery,
            xshift=\ctempfadebbcenterx,
          },
          tempstyle,
        ] (temp-fade-bb-ne) rectangle (temp-fade-bb-sw);
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Interestingly, I had to add a new command `\spath_set_current_softpath:n` to ensure that the fading picked up the arrow heads.  This will make its way into `spath3` at some point which is why I've wrapped it in a `\cs_if_exist:NF`.