# How to shade a region between two arcs of circle

Tags: shading

I would like to shade the region between the two geodesics `(a,b)` and `(b,c)` in such a way that the color fades as the region becomes wider.  This is the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%circle

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2];

% b

\filldraw (0,2) circle [radius=1pt];

\draw (0,2.3) node {$b$};

%a

\filldraw (-1,-1.73) circle [radius=1pt];

\draw (-1.2,-1.8) node {$a$};

%c

\filldraw (2,0) circle [radius=1pt];

\draw (2.3,0) node {$c$};

%geodesic (b,c)

\draw[name path=A, xshift=2cm, yshift=2cm, domain=180:270] plot(\x:2);

%geodesic (a,b)

\draw[name path=B, xshift=-6cm, yshift=1.6cm, domain=326:364] plot(\x:6);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody tell me how to do it, please?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use directional shadings, but "wider" is a nebulous concept.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gives my solution, hoping it will satisfy your requirement. The basic idea is ti use `\fill` to fill the region consisted of a -- geodesics (a,b) -- b -- geodesics (b, c) -- c -- geodesics (c, a) -- a.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%circle

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2];

% b

\filldraw (0,2) circle [radius=1pt];

\draw (0,2.3) node {$b$};

%a

\filldraw (-1,-1.73) circle [radius=1pt];

\draw (-1.2,-1.8) node {$a$};

%c

\filldraw (2,0) circle [radius=1pt];

\draw (2.3,0) node {$c$};

\fill [path fading=south,top color=green!80!white, bottom color=blue!80!white, variable=\x]
(-1,-1.73)
-- plot[domain=326:364]({6*cos(\x)-6},{6*sin(\x)+1.6})
-- (0,2)
-- plot[domain=180:270]({2*cos(\x)+2}, {2*sin(\x)+2})
-- (2,0)
-- plot[domain=240:360]({2*cos(\x)}, {2*sin(\x)})
-- (-1,-1.73);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The shading scheme is inspired by [Tikz: Shading a path without any filling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/tikz-shading-a-path-without-any-filling). However, this solution does not make the color shades as the region gets wider (maybe a more precise `path fading` setting will do).

The resulted figure looks as follows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Would shadedraw work instead of fill?  I might try, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that some of the earlier items got overdrawn.  Also, arcs are drawn from the end points and compute the centers based on the angle and radius.  Adding the `-- (B)` etc. wasn't necessary, but helped debugging the code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%circle
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2];
% b
\filldraw (0,2) coordinate(B) circle [radius=1pt] node[above] {$b$};
%a
\filldraw (-1,-1.73) coordinate(A) circle [radius=1pt] node[below left] {$a$};
%c
\filldraw (2,0) coordinate(C) circle [radius=1pt] node[right] {$c$};
%geodesic (b,c)
\draw (B) arc[start angle=180, end angle=270, radius=2];
%geodesic (a,b)
\draw (A) arc[start angle=326, end angle=360, radius=6];
%shading
\shadedraw[shading=axis,shading angle=30]
  (A) arc[start angle=326, end angle=360, radius=6] --
  (B) arc[start angle=180, end angle=270, radius=2] --
  (C) arc[start angle=360, end angle=240, radius=2] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks a lot @John.  I had tried to use arc to draw the arcs of the circle, but had not succeeded and found this other method with which I could not shade.  Thanks!