# Tikz: drawing border or line with shade

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a line with a shade, not a big rectangle.

As per the documentation,

> Shading is caused by the shade option (there are \shade and \shadedraw abbreviations).

Shouldn't therefore something like this work?

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [shade, left color=red, right color=blue] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I cannot get it to be shaded. It always shows up like this:[image: line]

---

In actuality, what I want to draw is a rectangle where the end of the borders are shaded this way:

[image: rectangle with shaded borders]

There is probably a simple way to do this, but I only see forms of doing filled shade, not border shades or single lines...

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Tikz: Shading a path without any filling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134283/13304)

Comment: Shading *is* only for areas, not lines. Edit: Also from the documentation: "*A shading is like a filling, ...*"

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I saw that solution, but it's overkill for my case. I don't want to use more than 100 lines when I just need a straight line. I will just draw lines as rectangles, as the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `path fading` from `fadings` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
  \tikz
    \draw[blue,thick,path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (4,1);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had tried that, but it also didn't work. I see now that solution doesn't work in the PDF viewer I use (Evince). I will go with the answer I posted in the comments (for interoperability's sake).

Answer (score 3):

As @Torbjørn T. pointed out, shading is a filling.

I have decided to just use rectangles of the size of a line (`\pgflinewidth`).

i.e.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\fadehline}[3]{
    \fill (#1,#3) rectangle ++(#2, \pgflinewidth);
    \shade[left color=black, right color=white] (#2,#3) rectangle ++(0.5, \pgflinewidth);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fadehline{0}{1}{0};
\fadehline{0}{1}{0.8};
\fill (0,0) rectangle ++(\pgflinewidth, 0.8);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]