# Crown with color gradient

Tags: tikz-pgf, gradient

How can I paint a crown (similar to the following) with color gradient? [image: crown]

I tried two different starting points:
First gradient rectangle with cuttings and second draw lines similar to the above picture. In the first case I have the problem, that I cannot identify clear the coordinates for the white spaces. In the second cases, I do not know how to create gradient colors on the lines. Anyway, the lines have strange endings/corners.
Both ideas are in my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,shading=axis,left color = {rgb,255:red,255;green,215;blue,0}, right color = {rgb,255:red,205;green,133;blue,63}, shading angle= 30, minimum width=8cm, minimum height=8cm] at (0,0) {};
\fill [white] (-4,-4) -- ++(0,8) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(-2,-8); %left cut
\fill [white] (4,-4) -- ++(0,8) -- ++(-2,0) -- ++(2,-8); % right cut
\fill [white] (0,4) -- (-2,0) -- (-4,3) -- (-4,4) -- (0,4); % 
\fill [white] (0,3.5) -- (-1.5,0) -- (0,-2) -- (1.5,0) -- (0,3.6); % white filling below top
\fill [white] (0,4) -- (2,0) -- (4,3) -- (4,4) -- (0,4); % 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=16pt]
\draw[line join=miter] (-6,-6) -- (0,6) -- (6,-6) -- (-6,-6) -- (0,6); %middle
\draw[line join=miter] (-6.2,-6.25) -- (-5.25,1.5) -- (-2,-6) -- (-6,-6); %left
\draw[line join=miter] (-5.3,1.7) -- (2,-6); %left
\draw[line join=miter] (6.2,-6.25) -- (5.25,1.5) -- (2,-6) -- (6,-6); %right
\draw[line join=miter] (5.25,1.5) -- (-2,-6); %right
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I found a solution that works but (in the code) looks ugly:

```
\fill[shading=axis,left color = {rgb,255:red,255;green,215;blue,0}, right color = {rgb,255:red,205;green,133;blue,63}, shading angle= 30] (0.01,-2.7) rectangle(2.99,-0.01) ;


\fill [white] (0,-2.7) -- (0.3,-0.75) -- (0.8,-1.3)-- (1.5,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,-2.7); % 
\fill [white] (3,-2.7) -- (2.7,-0.75) -- (2.2,-1.3)-- (1.5,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,-2.7); % 
\fill [white] (0.2,-2.4) -- (0.57,-1.72) -- (0.37,-1.18); % 
\fill [white] (0.53,-1.22) -- (0.73,-1.42) -- (0.66,-1.56); % 
\fill [white] (0.27,-2.56) -- (0.90,-2.56) -- (0.64,-1.89); % 
\fill [white] (1.03,-2.5) -- (1.41,-2.11) -- (0.84,-1.53) -- (0.73,-1.72); % 

\fill [white] (2.8,-2.4) -- (2.43,-1.72) -- (2.63,-1.18); % 
\fill [white] (2.47,-1.22) -- (2.27,-1.42) -- (2.34,-1.56); % 
\fill [white] (2.73,-2.56) -- (2.10,-2.56) -- (2.36,-1.89); % 
\fill [white] (1.97,-2.5) -- (1.59,-2.11) -- (2.16,-1.53) -- (2.27,-1.72); % 

\fill [white] (1.5,-2.0) -- (2.11,-1.4) -- (1.5,-0.33) -- (0.89,-1.4); % 
\fill [white] (1.5,-2.22) -- (1.85,-2.56) -- (1.15,-2.56); %
```

The code was generated by copying the image to graphic programme and looking at the pixel-coordinates. This 'solution' has another weakness: If I want thinner or fatter lines, than I have to create a new image with a graphic programme and look at the coordinates again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I clean up the document and coordinates, to keep everything within one smooth shape - you can adjust the coordinates to your liking:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=16pt]
\draw (-6,-6) -- (0,6) -- (6,-6);
\draw[red] (-6,-6) -- (-5.25,1.5) -- (2,-6) -- cycle;
\draw[green] (6,-6) -- (5.25,1.5) -- (-2,-6) -- cycle;
\draw[blue] (-5.25,1.5) -- (-2,-6);
\draw[yellow] (5.25,1.5) -- (2,-6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Black, red, green, blue, yellow crown]

The same in black, with one path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=16pt]
\draw (-6,-6) -- (0,6) -- (6,-6) (-6,-6) -- (-5.25,1.5) -- (2,-6) -- cycle (6,-6) -- (5.25,1.5) -- (-2,-6) -- cycle (-5.25,1.5) -- (-2,-6) (5.25,1.5) -- (2,-6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Black crown]

Now I am stuck - it does not work with the `fadings` library, and I have been reading the manual and many posts on this site - it can be done with methods involving custom code from e.g. [Tikz: Shading a path without any filling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/tikz-shading-a-path-without-any-filling)

In this attempt, there are several things I do not fully understand - e.g. the scaling. Some writes that a custom fading needs to be 2cmx2cm while others use 1cmx1cm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
 \fill[transparent!0](-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
 \draw[scale=0.1, line width=1.6pt,  path fading=west](-6,-6) -- (0,6) -- (6,-6) (-6,-6) -- (-5.25,1.5) -- (2,-6) -- cycle (6,-6) -- (5.25,1.5) -- (-2,-6) -- cycle (-5.25,1.5) -- (-2,-6) (5.25,1.5) -- (2,-6);
 \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[path fading=myfading, fill=black] (-6,-6) rectangle (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Black and white faded crown]

**Edit:**

By using the comment from OP, and the colors from OP, I get this result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\draw[scale=0.1, line width=2pt,  transparent!0](-6,-6) -- (0,6) -- (6,-6) (-6,-6) -- (-5.5,2) -- (2,-6) -- cycle (6,-6) -- (5.5,2) -- (-2,-6) -- cycle (-5.5,2) -- (-2,-6) (5.5,2) -- (2,-6);  \fill[black, path fading=north, fading angle = 195](-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);  
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[path fading=myfading, left color = {rgb,255:red,255;green,215;blue,0}, right color = {rgb,255:red,205;green,133;blue,63}] (-6,-6) rectangle (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Yellow faded crown]

There is still the problem with the unexplained scaling.

Comment: By changing a little the "myfading". I got a solution that works for me. Thank you very much:`\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading2]
  \draw[scale=0.1, line width=2pt,  transparent!0](-6,-6) -- (0,6) -- (6,-6) (-6,-6) -- (-5.5,2) -- (2,-6) -- cycle (6,-6) -- (5.5,2) -- (-2,-6) -- cycle (-5.5,2) -- (-2,-6) (5.5,2) -- (2,-6);
 \fill[black, path fading=north, fading angle = 195](-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
 \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}`