# Issue with fade-no-fill.sty

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, tikz-path

I’m trying to have colour gradient on path, and discovered fade-no-fill.sty, which latest version seems to be https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567029/56823. It works pretty well, but I have two small issues.

My MWE is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{fade-no-fill}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{3}
    \node [red,draw,thick,ellipse] (S) at (-\l,0) {Solide};
    \node [blue,draw,thick,ellipse] (L) at (\l,0) {Liquide};
    \node [green,draw,thick,ellipse] (G) at (0,{\l*sqrt(3)}) {Gaz};
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{bottom color=red,top color=green}] (S) to[bend left] (G);
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{top color=green,bottom color=blue}] (G) to[bend left] (L);
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{right color=blue,left color=red}] (L) to[bend left] (S);
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{left color=red,right color=blue}] (S) to (L);
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{top color=green,bottom color=blue}] (L) to (G);
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{bottom color=red,top color=green}] (G) to (S);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces this:
[image: MWE output]
Note:

1. the clipped blue arrow above “Liquide”.
2. the very strange arrow at the left of “Liquide”.

Any idea what could be causing this and how to solve it?

Comment: Try adding \usetikzlibrary{bending}

Comment: Have you tried suggestion from @Ross? (I do not know what it does, but try it) Also add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` "% needed so that bounding boxes correctly include arrows." (should already be in `fade-no-fill.sty` - but try it)

Comment: Try this (maybe it will expand the bounding box) `\path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{top color=green,bottom color=blue}] (G) to[bend left] (L) edge[draw=none] ([turn] 90:0.2);`

Comment: There is another fading question, where the arrowhead gets cut of - maybe you can draw the head separately like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597939/8650

Comment: It is almost certainly an issue with the arrowheads not being included in the bounding box calculations. If you imagine a rectangle around each path then you can see why they get flipped but the others don't.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Yes. In a normal `path fading`, it looks like the bounding box is doubled(but apparently not here) so that only when lines are near horizontal/vertical arrow heads are clipped. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/597927/8650

Comment: @Ross solution does nothing, but this is indeed definitively a clipping issue.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I’ve indeed figured out a solution redrawing the arrows head that I’ve added as a solution just before you’ve posted this comment. I’m now looking into the other ones proposed since.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`> = latex` is an arrow tip without bounding box.
(This arrow head is defined in `pgfcorearrows.code.tex`
and is available regardless of whether `arrows.meta` is included.)

With `> = Latex`, the arrow tip has a bounding box.
(This arrow head is defined in `arrows.meta` with proper bounding box.)

Comment: Cool. Do you know why it goes wrong for the normal `->` here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/597927/8650 ?

Comment: I also answered that question =P. It has something to do with the order of computation. (fading comes before adding arrow heads.)

Comment: Wow - You effortlessly jumped back in time and answered, just to make me look stupid :o)

Comment:  (dummy parentheses to meet mim char requirement)

Comment: Interesting, good to know. I’m accepting this answer since this is the one correctly solving clipping while using fade-no-fill, but @hpekristiansen new solution with twice drawing is also nice to work without fade-no-fill. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is another methode where all the arrows are drawn twice with two different colors `path fading` from different directions.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[red,draw,thick,ellipse] (S) at (-3,0) {Solide};
\node[blue,draw,thick,ellipse] (L) at (3,0) {Liquide};
\node[green,draw,thick,ellipse] (G) at (0,{3*sqrt(3)}) {Gaz};
\draw[green, path fading=south, thick ,-latex] (S) to[bend left] (G);
\draw[red, path fading=north, thick ,-latex] (S) to[bend left] (G);
\draw[green, path fading=south, thick ,-latex] (G) to[bend left] (L);
\draw[blue, path fading=north, thick ,-latex] (G) to[bend left] (L);
\draw[blue, path fading=west, thick ,-latex] (L) to[bend left] (S);
\draw[red, path fading=east, thick ,-latex] (L) to[bend left] (S);
\draw[blue, path fading=west, thick, shorten >=5pt] (S) to (L); %this arror is problematic
\draw[blue, thick ,-latex] ([xshift=-4pt] L.west) -- (L.west); %seperate arrow head
\draw[red, path fading=east, thick ,-latex] (S) to (L);
\draw[green, path fading=south, thick ,-latex] (L) to (G);
\draw[blue, path fading=north, thick ,-latex] (L) to (G);
\draw[green, path fading=south, thick ,-latex] (G) to (S);
\draw[red, path fading=north, thick ,-latex] (G) to (S);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Diagram with color fading arrows]

The horizontal blue arrow head gets clipped, but is redrawn. A more universal method is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597939/8650

**Edit:**

The double drawing can be made into a style with a `postaction` here is a start:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\foreach \a in {0,10,...,360}{
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (\a:3);
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(A)$), \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in [green, path fading=west, fading angle = \n1, thick ,-latex, postaction={draw, red, path fading=east, fading angle = \n1, thick ,-latex}]  ([xshift=5pt, yshift=5pt]A) (A) to[bend left] (B);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red and green arrow wheel]

Comment: This is a very nice solution and I might actually switch to that, however I’ve accepted @symbol-1 solution since it properly fixes the clipping answer in the context of the question (using fade-no-fill). But I’ve upvoted you on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615816/56823 ;)

Comment: I agree Symbol1 answered your question. (but this is probably a nicer solution)

Comment: Actually it’s not just the arrow that gets clipped, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615945/56823

Answer (score 4):

Since we are into workarounds, I’ve tried this one:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{fade-no-fill}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{3}
    \node [red,draw,thick,ellipse] (S) at (-\l,0) {Solide};
    \node [blue,draw,thick,ellipse] (L) at (\l,0) {Liquide};
    \node [green,draw,thick,ellipse] (G) at (0,{\l*sqrt(3)}) {Gaz};
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{bottom color=red,top color=green}] (S) to[bend left] (G);
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{top color=green,bottom color=blue}] (G) to[bend left] (L);
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{right color=blue,left color=red}] (L) to[bend left] (S);
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{left color=red,right color=blue}] (S) to (L);
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{top color=green,bottom color=blue}] (L) to (G);
    \path [fade path but don't fill={thick,->,>=latex,transparent!0}{bottom color=red,top color=green}] (G) to (S);
    \draw [thick,<-,>=latex,blue] (L.west) -- ++(-0.1,0); % Redraw west arrow
    \draw [thick,<-,>=latex,blue] (L.north) -- ++(0,0.1); % Redraw north arrow
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result with workaround]
The result suits me, but this is still a workaround nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know `\usepackage{fade-no-fill}`, but here is an alternative solution using `tikzfadingfrompicture`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, fadings, shadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{3}
\node[transparent!0,draw,thick,ellipse] (S) at (-\l,0) {Solide};
\node[transparent!0,draw,thick,ellipse] (L) at (\l,0) {Liquide};
\node[transparent!0,draw,thick,ellipse] (G) at (0,{\l*sqrt(3)}) {Gaz};
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (S) to[bend left] (G);
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (G) to[bend left] (L);
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (L) to[bend left] (S);
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (S) to (L);
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (L) to (G);
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (G) to (S);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[lower left=red, lower right=blue, upper left=green, upper right=green, path fading=myfading, fit fading=false] (-3.9,-3.3) rectangle (4.1,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three nodes with color faded arrows]

**Edit:**

I just got an idea of how to prevent translation of the `tikzfadingfrompicture` - simply add a `circle` centered at `(0,0)` that encompasses everything.

`\draw[transparent!100] (0,0) circle (6);`. Now the `node`s can be drawn outside the fading, if so desired:

[image: Same graph, but with mono colored nodes]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, fadings, shadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\node[transparent!100,draw,thick,ellipse] (S) at (-3,0) {Solide};
\node[transparent!100,draw,thick,ellipse] (L) at (3,0) {Liquide};
\node[transparent!100,draw,thick,ellipse] (G) at (0,{3*sqrt(3)}) {Gaz};
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (S) to[bend left] (G);
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (G) to[bend left] (L);
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (L) to[bend left] (S);
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (S) to (L);
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (L) to (G);
\draw[transparent!0, thick ,-latex] (G) to (S);
\draw[transparent!100] (0,0) circle (6);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[lower left=red, lower right=blue, upper left=green, upper right=green, path fading=myfading, fit fading=false] (-4,-1.2) rectangle (4.1,5.8);
\node[red,draw,thick,ellipse] (S) at (-3,0) {Solide};
\node[blue,draw,thick,ellipse] (L) at (3,0) {Liquide};
\node[green,draw,thick,ellipse] (G) at (0,{3*sqrt(3)}) {Gaz};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! This is very interesting. I didn't know about this `tikzfadingfrompicture` environment. I'll dig into it (since it's in the manual).

Comment: @SebGlav I find it difficult to work with and not well described. `fit fading=false` prevents scaling of the fading picture, but there will be a translation. I unsuccessfully tried to have the nodes outside the fading, but I can not make the placement predictable.

Comment: @SebGlav: Ok - I guess, that I now have an idea, of how to hack the translation.

Comment: This is an interesting alternative, but unfortunately I indeed don’t want nodes inside the fading, and your solution doing that is having issues with colour gradient not ending with the node colour (since they still take the ellipses into account). I guess I could hack something using a fadingfrompicture for each of the arrow?