# Draw line in tikz with changing color

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have the following line using `\draw` (see MWE below). I would like to have the line change in color, from red on the right, to blue on the left. Current attempts are adding a fading region rather than changing the color of the line itself.

Note that [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/tikz-shading-a-path-without-any-filling) by percusse offers a solution, using a custom fade, but I'm not sure how to edit it to get the effect I'm looking for. I would ideally like to add an edit to `\draw[...]` that achieves this effect.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [ultra thick,red] (-19.5,-16) to[out=55,in=228] (-14,-9) to [out=45,in=180] (0,-2) to[out=0,in=135] (14, -9) to[out=315,in=125] (20,-16);       
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it shaded I have a (dirty) but quick solution. Use `shade` and add a filled white version in front:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=white] (-19.35,-16.01) to[out=55,in=228] (-13.8,-9) to [out=45,in=180] (0,-2.15) to[out=0,in=135] (13.8, -9) to[out=315,in=125] (19.85,-16.01); 
    
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background} 
            \shade[left color=blue, right color=red, very thick] (-19.5,-16) to[out=55,in=228] (-14,-9) to [out=45,in=180] (0,-2) to[out=0,in=135] (14, -9) to[out=315,in=125] (20,-16);  
        \end{pgfonlayer} 
   
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

This is the effect I think you are looking for without any custom fading.
[image]

Comment: The later answer was indeed what I was looking for

Comment: Is it possible to add a `left opacity` and `right opacity`? I'm looking for a bit more control that `path fading=west`. Something that controls where the fading/opacity starts